# Trying to project a single document from a deeply nested collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with deeply nested documents. specifically, my hierarchy is as follows: client > project > room.

My goal is to be able to use clientId, projectId, and roomId, to filter and project this collection so that only the desired room comes back from the database. Rooms might have many logs and other data elements attached to them, and it seems wasteful to pull them all back and filter them in client code.

I would like to avoid splitting the collection into multiple collections.

I am not using an ORM like mongoose etc, and I would like to leave those out of the equation from now, as this is largely a learning exercise to sharpen my MongoDB skills.

I have tried using the projection $ operator, which works well for the first level nested array,

With this data structure:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0b9"), 
    "clienttype" : "Residential", 
    "name" : "Bob", 
    "projects" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0ba"), 
            "name" : "First Project", 
            "rooms" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5f1a9d354c541edd2eac8e"), 
                    "name" : "Room 1", 
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5f1d6b354c541edd2eac8f"), 
                    "name" : "Room 2", 
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0bb"), 
            "name" : "Second Project", 
            "rooms" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5f1da6354c541edd2eac96"), 
                    "name" : "Room 3", 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to run this query with success:

```
  db.getCollection("clients").find({
   "_id": ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0b9"),
   "projects._id": ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0ba")
  },
  {
    "projects.$":1
  })
```

Where I run into trouble is as follows...

using multiple positional operators (obviously not allowed):

```
db.getCollection("clients").find({
   "_id": ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0b9"),
   "projects._id": ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0ba"),
   "projects.rooms._id": ObjectId("5c5f1d6b354c541edd2eac8f")
  },
  {
    "projects.$.rooms.$":1
  })
```

attempting to omit the first $ as indicated by a few answers here on SO, which executes, but fails to filter the rooms collection:

```
db.getCollection("clients").find({
   "_id": ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0b9"),
   "projects._id": ObjectId("5c3a3fc7e72812c33ed9a0ba"),
   "projects.rooms._id": ObjectId("5c5f1d6b354c541edd2eac8f")
  },
  {
    "projects.rooms.$":1
  })
```

It seems as though since I can update, insert, and delete from collections as deeply nested as I like using array filters $[], there should be a way to retrieve just a single document from a deeply nested collection as well.

Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: I have some input about this: 1) if this is a common query and it sounds too difficult for your day-to-day operation, it might be fragile and hard to change in the future. 2) have you tried running `db.clients.explain('executionStats').find(...)` and see how MongoDB plans to execute it? 3) why the aversion toward splitting this into multiple collections? If the use case requires it and it's the easiest way forward, why not do it? 4) have a look at https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 and see if it provides you with a guidance.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha honestly, a lot of my motivation falls under the "stupid coding tricks" category. It's more of a desire to figure out how to manage deep nesting rather than a specific business need at this time (this is a silly personal project). I haven't tried explain, I always forget about it, I will do that now. As for not wanting to split it, i am not using an ORM and mongo's lack of referential integrity checks makes me a little nervous at times.

Comment: You might be interested in this blog: http://www.askasya.com/ there are many different tips & tricks there.